# Group rows of a multidimensional array by month of a d/m/Y formatted date column value and reformat date in each row

Tags: php, arrays, date, multidimensional-array, grouping

Below is my json and I convert json to php array and then try to group it by months, so that same month data stays in one array, like feb month data under one array. I have tried using foreach to start,  but I'm not getting the correct result.

Below is my code:

```php
{

  "exam_dates": [

    {"id":"1","uni_name":"uni1","exam_name":"University of Szeged Feb","exam_date":"02\/02\/2022","exam_mode":"Online","appl_deadline":"To be announced"},
    {"id":"2","uni_name":"uni2","exam_name":"University of Szeged","exam_date":"21\/02\/2022","exam_mode":"Online","appl_deadline":"To be announced"},
    {"id":"3","uni_name":"uni3","exam_name":"University of Szeged","exam_date":"22\/02\/2022","exam_mode":"Online","appl_deadline":"To be announced"},
    {"id":"4","uni_name":"uni4","exam_name":"University of Szeged","exam_date":"32\/03\/2022","exam_mode":"Online","appl_deadline":"To be announced"}

  ]

}

$data = json_decode($body);
```

Required output using its month from exam_date:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [February] => stdClass Object
                (

                [0] => Array
                    [id] => 1
                    [uni_name] => University of Szeged Feb
                    [exam_name] => University of Szeged Feb
                    [exam_date] => 02/08/2022
                    [exam_mode] => Online
                    [appl_deadline] => To be announced
                )

                [1] => Array
                    [id] => 1
                    [uni_name] => University of Szeged Feb
                    [exam_name] => University of Szeged Feb
                    [exam_date] => 02/08/2022
                    [exam_mode] => Online
                    [appl_deadline] => To be announced
               )

                 [2] => Array
                        [id] => 1
                        [uni_name] => University of Szeged Feb
                        [exam_name] => University of Szeged Feb
                        [exam_date] => 02/08/2022
                        [exam_mode] => Online
                        [appl_deadline] => To be announced
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [March] => stdClass Object
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [uni_name] => University of Szeged
                        [exam_name] => University of Szeged
                        [exam_date] => 03/06/2022
                        [exam_mode] => Online
                        [appl_deadline] => To be announced
                    )
            )
        )

)
```

**I tried using this but not close yet:**

```php
foreach ($data->exam_dates as $edates) {

    $month_name =  date("F", strtotime($edates->exam_date));

    $month_key[][$month_name] = $edates;

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($month_key);

}
```

Comment: First issue: strtotime can't parse those date formats properly.

Comment: Second issue: `$month_key[][$month_name] = ...` will create a _new_ element on the top level each time, even if the month is the same. Not sure what the point of having this extra level in the desired result is in the first place, but if you really need it, you will still have to gather your data grouped by month name first, and then "move all elements one level down" afterwards.

Comment: DO you really have a date `32\/03\/2022`???

Answer (score 1):

You were really close. Basically all you needed to do was change this line

```
$month_key[][$month_name] = $edates;
```

To

```
$month_key[$month_name][] = $edates;
```

But it would be better to also use a more reliable way of date manipulation so I used the builtin DateTime class instead of `strtodate()` and `date()`

```
$body = '{

    "exam_dates": [
  
      {"id":"1","uni_name":"uni1","exam_name":"University of Szeged Feb","exam_date":"02\/02\/2022","exam_mode":"Online","appl_deadline":"To be announced"},
      {"id":"2","uni_name":"uni2","exam_name":"University of Szeged","exam_date":"21\/02\/2022","exam_mode":"Online","appl_deadline":"To be announced"},
      {"id":"3","uni_name":"uni3","exam_name":"University of Szeged","exam_date":"22\/02\/2022","exam_mode":"Online","appl_deadline":"To be announced"},
      {"id":"4","uni_name":"uni4","exam_name":"University of Szeged","exam_date":"22\/03\/2022","exam_mode":"Online","appl_deadline":"To be announced"}
  
    ]
  
  }';
  
$data = json_decode($body);
#print_r($data);

foreach ($data->exam_dates as $edates) {

    $d = (new DateTime())->CreateFromFormat('d/m/Y',$edates->exam_date);
    // get month name
    $month_name = $d->format('F');
    //format date to USA format
    $edates->exam_date = $d->format('m/d/Y');

    $month_key[$month_name][] = $edates;
}
print_r($month_key);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [February] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [uni_name] => uni1
                    [exam_name] => University of Szeged Feb
                    [exam_date] => 02/02/2022
                    [exam_mode] => Online
                    [appl_deadline] => To be announced
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [uni_name] => uni2
                    [exam_name] => University of Szeged
                    [exam_date] => 02/21/2022
                    [exam_mode] => Online
                    [appl_deadline] => To be announced
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [uni_name] => uni3
                    [exam_name] => University of Szeged
                    [exam_date] => 02/22/2022
                    [exam_mode] => Online
                    [appl_deadline] => To be announced
                )

        )

    [March] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [uni_name] => uni4
                    [exam_name] => University of Szeged
                    [exam_date] => 03/22/2022
                    [exam_mode] => Online
                    [appl_deadline] => To be announced
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by months alone without taking the year into account doesn't make much sense. That's why I took the year with me into the key. In addition, the date format is poorly chosen.

```
$groupedArray = [];
foreach($data->exam_dates as $dates){
  $key = dateTime::createFromFormat('!d/m/Y',$dates->exam_date)->format('F Y');
  $groupedArray[$key][] = $dates;
}
```

$groupedArray =

```
array (
  'February 2022' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    (object) array(
       'id' => "1",
       'uni_name' => "uni1",
       // :
```